# How to Change color of KML polygon on mouse click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a KML file where lots of polygon drawn and I want to change color of polygon on mouse click so that it is looking that polygon is selected.

**Problem:** I loaded the KML file but not able to get its polygon so that I can implemented click listener.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Looking to do this in Google Earth using just the KML or within Google Maps context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **afterParse** attribute to give a callback and assign event handler there

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" ></div>
</body>

<script>
function initialize(){
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

var myOptions = {  
          zoom: 18,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
           // zoom: 5,
           // center: myLatlng,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
                afterParse: myfunction
            });
 geoXml.parse('bs-stadium.kml');
 }

 function myfunction(doc)
 {
   google.maps.event.addListener(doc,"mouseover",function() {
     for (var i=0;i<doc.gpolylines.length;i++) 
       doc.gpolylines[i].setOptions({strokeColor: "#FFFF00"});
   });

    google.maps.event.addListener(doc,"mouseout",function() {
      for (var i=0;i<doc.gpolylines.length;i++) 
        doc.gpolylines[i].setOptions({strokeColor: "#00FFFF"});
    });
 }
 </script>
```

**UPDATE:**
Try the code below i tested and its working edit wherever necessary

for kml make a file name it demo.kml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document>
  <name>tennis-lines</name>
  <open>1</open>
  <Placemark>
  <name>outside</name>
  <LineString>
    <coordinates>
      -122.43193945401,37.801983684521
      -122.431564131101,37.8020327731402
      -122.431499536494,37.801715236748
      -122.43187136387,37.8016634915437
      -122.43193945401,37.801983684521
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <name>west</name>
  <LineString>
    <coordinates>
      -122.431885303019,37.8019316061803
      -122.431762847554,37.8019476932246
      -122.431719843168,37.8017374462006
      -122.431841863906,37.8017213314352
      -122.431885303019,37.8019316061803
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <name>east</name>
  <LineString>
    <coordinates>
      -122.431714248439,37.8019544341044
      -122.431592404659,37.8019694509363
      -122.431548777661,37.8017591041777
      -122.431671453253,37.8017428443014
      -122.431714248439,37.8019544341044
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

now this is the html file

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">
   html, body, #map_canvas {
     width:   300px;
     height:  300px;
     margin:  0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var geoXml = null;
    var map = null;
    var myLatLng = null;

    function initialize() {
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 18,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851),
                // zoom: 5,
                // center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                  myOptions);

   geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
                afterParse: useTheData
            });
            geoXml.parse('demo.kml');
        };


 function highlightPoly(poly) {
    poly.setOptions({strokeColor: "#0000FF"});
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseover",function() {
    poly.setOptions({strokeColor: "#ee0000"});
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function() {
    poly.setOptions({strokeColor: "#00ee00"});
    });
 }  

 function useTheData(doc){
   geoXmlDoc = doc[0];
   for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].gpolylines.length; i++) {
     highlightPoly(doc[0].gpolylines[i]);
   }

 };

</script>
</head>


<body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="map_canvas">
    </div>

    <div id="map_text">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Couldn't post fiddle due to origin policy .Hopefully that helps.

Comment: above code show:-ReferenceError: geoXML3 is not defined but i have already added this js.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>

Comment: Make sure  geoxml3 script is included in the head part and before the code i have told.

Comment: use this link for geoxml https://rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js

Comment: I am also using the same js as you provided.

Comment: @Ritesh Paliwal as you didn't post your code it's really hard to say anything ,anyways try the code in the update section  i have tested it to work

Comment: Thanks Pixel for the code.But still I am getting the parsing error.
XML parse error
>Unable to retrieve http:/xyz.com/demo/demo.kml
>TypeError: doc[0].gpolylines is undefined
>for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].gpolylines.length; i++) {

Comment: Your kml file couldn't be found check the paths and filenames adjust the path in html file  if xml file is in different folder